# What is the conditional distribution of a variable with a Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

More specifically: if $X$ is a $k-$dimensional vector with a Dirichlet distribution, what is the probability that $X_i>a$, given $X_j>b$, where $a$ and $b$ are both in $(0,1)$ and $i\neq j$? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and why you could not finish answering?